# bitwise And operation in javascript & in C#

Tags: javascript

I am converting C# code into javascript where I need to perform bitwise AND operation.

C# code is returning different result than javascript.

(3433343494547833 & 0xFFFF000000000000) = 3377699720527872

javascript code

```
(3433343494547833 & 0xFFFF000000000000) = 0
```

Could anyone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: `0xFFFF...` is greater than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. C# you're probably using a double whereas JS only has floats.

Comment: @zzzzBov in addition, bitwise operations in JS are only performed on 32-bit numbers and anything larger than that is going to be forcefully converted. So the maximum safe integer for bitwise arithmetic is `2147483647` (2^31 - 1)

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. Curious to know is it limitation with JS? Is there some workaround ?

Comment: @Gyandeep you will need to use a third party library if you need big numbers, like [this one](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/). I don't think that one supports bitwise operations, but I believe there might be others that do.